# How to show big text in IE9

Tags: css, text, internet-explorer-9, font-size

I want to show big text only in Ie9. I have a lot of div and span used in my page. I can't write for every div a css line.

I want to write a single css to applied on whole page. I want to applied it on IE9 only.

```
*{
font-size:120%;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Target IE9 Only via CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654423/target-ie9-only-via-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ben Lee, this is something you should do with a conditional statement.

```
 <!--[if IE 9]>
 <style type="text/css">
  *{
   font-size:120%;
  }
   </style>
   <![endif]-->
```