# ie9 vs chrome ie causing problems changing header

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, testing, cross-browser

but having problems viewing it on ie.

how can i make my code good for ie

what is the best way

this is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/Jntuw/

might be

```
h1 {
color: #A9218E;
font-family: 'LeagueGothic';
 font-size: 2.9em;

}
```

the header changes in ie9

sometimes the border shows lines.

Comment: Please fix your JSFiddle link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jntuw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Take out the inline styles and add to your stylesheet.
- Style the table in the CSS.

  **table {border:0;}**

  **th {}**

  **td {}**

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp - this should help

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

Just put this in your header!

```
    <!--[if IE 9]> IE 9 style content goes here <![endif]-->
```

[Target IE9 Only via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654423/target-ie9-only-via-css)

Comment: yeah but what content do i put