# Cant define a CSS rule only for IE9 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I want to define a CSS rule for IE9 and below ONLY so I included this line on my style sheet:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
.gradient {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (GradientType=0, startColorstr=#bbb69c, endColorstr=#ffffff)";
}
<![endif]-->
```

it didnt work. Internet Explorer 9 is not understanding it unless I take off the conditional tags.

Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: Which conditional tags you are trying? Can you show us HTML code for it?

Comment: This seems to a duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654423/target-ie9-only-via-css. If not a duplicate you can use the idea.

Comment: Check this site https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Ah yes, conditional comments only work in HTML, not in CSS.

Comment: Thank you but I dont need to create a new style sheet for IE only. I want to include that line in my current style sheet.

Comment: @CainNuke Well, you'll have to create a new one.

Comment: **Moderator note**: a gentle reminder to keep the tone civil and respectful.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add HTML code inside conditional comments. Your page structure should be like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <body>
        // body content goes here...
    </body>
</html>
```

And in ie9.css you can define your css

```
.gradient {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (GradientType=0, startColorstr=#bbb69c, endColorstr=#ffffff)";
}
```

Comment: I knew that trick already but I want to do it within the same style sheet.

Comment: @CainNuke Yeah, you said you wanted to do that, but sometimes one just has to abide by the rules.

Comment: If there is really no way to do what I intend I will give it up. But I am pretty convinced there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded the css in style tag.

```
<html class="ie9-fix">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <!--[if IE]>
       <style>
.gradient {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (GradientType=0, startColorstr=#bbb69c, endColorstr=#ffffff)";
}
</style>
    <![endif]-->
    <body>
        // body content goes here...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not bad, but I really dont want to mess with the html. Only the css.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found the answer. This seems to work.

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
gradient {-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (GradientType=0, startColorstr=#bbb69c, endColorstr=#ffffff)";
}
```