# Make div width 100% when the div next to it is pushed down the page

Tags: css

CSS gurus, I'm back with another probably lame question. I have two divs next to eachother. I want to meet the following two conditions:

1. When there is enough space for both on the page, they should have 50% width and be on the same row.
2. When there isnt enough space - they should be 100% width and on top of eachother.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kwg1upu0/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="divOne"></div>
 <div class="divTwo"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.divOne { 
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.divTwo {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
```

**EDIT:** Indeed Media Queries are the correct answer which I marked. Keep in mind that media queries will only apply on page load, so the change won't happen dynamically as you resize the window. In my case I need that, so I will have to do it programatically with Angular and $window.innerWidth.

Comment: What do you mean by enough space? Width or height?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I was referring to width.

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/k6o2jpk7/

Comment: Thanks mate, this is exactly what I was looking for. You can post it as an answer so I can upvote it too. Thanks :)

Comment: I asked myself a similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846700/how-to-force-a-block-container-to-take-always-all-the-available-width. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: @Eria what you asked is a combination of my question here, and a question I asked yesterday - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126074/css-center-div-child-of-two-pairs-of-divs/ - Basically you need to do both of them. I'll give it a try once I get this done :)

Comment: Yes, I had specific constraints that didn't ease my way.

Comment: If you use @media screen and (max-width:600px), then the change will happen as you resize the window.

Comment: Welcome @Neekboy :) Np, Your problem is solved, that is more important than upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a media query.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.divOne {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.divTwo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .divOne, .divTwo {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="divOne"></div>
 <div class="divTwo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Funny thing that just yesterday I read about media queries, should have though of them. Thanks for your time, cheers :)

Comment: You can mark it as the answer, so everybody will directly see it :-)

Comment: It doesn't allow me for 4 more minutes, will mark as the correct answer as soon as the cooldown is off :)

Comment: This gives the divs a fixed width of 300px, when the screen width is above 600px. You wanted the divs to fill the page 50% each. See my answer below.

Comment: @tigerdi thats right, i updated the answer. He only needed to update the fixed width to a percantage width. The OPs question got answered with the `media query`:-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this properly is with media queries. 
See fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kwg1upu0/6/

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .divOne, .divTwo {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Once the width of the page is 600px or less, then change it to 100% width.