# CSS media query not working in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I have included some media queries in my design to change the width of some elements of the page based on the browser's width. The queries look like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px)
@media screen and (max-width:1024px)
```

Chrome, Safari and Firefox work great, only IE is a problem. I know that all versions prior to IE 9 don't support this feature, but they don't work in IE 9 at all. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you have compatibility mode turned on?

Comment: Compatibility mode was turned on. Turning it off solved the issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem too ... thought I'd mention in case it helps anyone else that on my IE9 Under "Compatibility View Settings" it had the "Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View" option ticked, which appeared to be the default ??? and this was affecting sites served from my WAMP server

Comment: Is Compatibility Mode a default mode on IE9 ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have right DOCTYPE declaration.
It's strongly recommended that websites use the HTML5 document type in order to support the widest variety of established and emerging standards (in this case: CSS3), as well as the broadest range of web browsers:  `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

use the following conditions

```
@media only screen (min-width: 1px) and (max-width:599px)
```

instead of

```
@media only screen (max-width:599px)
```

and make sure `min-width` is `1px` as IE9 doesn't pickup `0px`

Answer (score -6):

Unfortunately min-width is simply not supported in any version of IE.  So if you use this convention:

```
<!---  CSS Selector :: Desktop --->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width:960px)" label="desktop">

<!---  CSS Selector :: Tablet PC --->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:959px)" label="tablet">

<!---  CSS Selector :: Phone --->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/phone.css" media="screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:499px)" label="phone">
```

It will ignore it all.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#media).

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a workaround.  And according to your 'Reference' link, IE 7-9 all support `min-width`.