# IE9 ignoring *some* media queries in same stylesheet

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a responsive site located here: http://wnmu.edu
Everything seems to be working just fine in all other modern browsers except IE9.

It seems like only certain @media queries are being recognize, even though they are in the same stylesheet. Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

The menu "About WNMU, Current Students..." is visible, which is originally hidden in less than 480px screens. However, the hamburger menu is still visible. My css code seems pretty simple:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 784px){
    .banner #responsive_menu_toggles {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I have capability mode off.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this the same bug?: if you open the hamburger menu and resize the window, you cannot close it and the display will stay in phone/tablet mode (at least in IE and Chrome)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. Just figured it out. I guess IE9 has a "4094 rule" limit. So I broke apart the css file, and everything is good! I'll definitely see why I have so many rules.

Sigh of relief.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this question was asked once before, here.

[Media query not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418139/media-query-not-working-in-ie9)

> Just in case anyone is crawling SO for an answer to this, the above
>   two answers aren't solving the core problem which is answered here -
>   [CSS media query not working in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917639/css-media-query-not-working-in-ie-9)
>
> Basically inline CSS3 media queries DO work in IE9 but you have to
>   disable Compatibilty mode -
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
> ```
>
> The above meta tag needs to be placed **before** any other meta tags otherwise IE9 will default to compatibility mode on and will subsequently not work.

If you are curious I found this by searching google for `ie9 @media css issues`

Comment: As I mentioned in my post "I have capability mode off." I saw this post. I'm using "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">" which is essentially the same thing. If you load the page in IE9 you will see that compatible mode does not run on the page.

Comment: Oh I missed that bit at the end, sorry :(