# How to target tablets but not IE9 using a media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am finding that IE9 is taking on tablet styles for my site.

```
@media (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait),
       (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)
{
    /* tablet styles */
}
```

The above media query is applied in IE9 when the browser's width is 1024px.

Having done some research, I found the following question/solution and it offers an explanation as to why this is happening.

[Media query not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418139/media-query-not-working-in-ie9)

> From what I can tell, it comes down to IE9 not interpreting
>   "min-device-width" and "max-device-width".
>
> According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms530813.aspx it does
>   not support those properties, only "min-width" and "max-width".
>
> In addition, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#error-handling
>   states that the browser is supposed to ignore properties that it does
>   not recognize. Not so with IE9 it seems.

I also found this question: [Common breakpoints for media queries on a responsive site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564752/good-widths-for-media-queries-on-responsive-site) but it doesn't give me a solution.

How can I apply my stylesheet only to tablets and not to desktop browsers like IE9 at a 1024px width?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this meta tag in the `<head>` of your document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And then in your css you can replace:

- `min-device-width` with `min-width`
- `max-device-width` with `max-width`.

Comment: Yeah did help, I didn't realise that you could do that have upvoted. I still found that other browsers were taking on the tablets styles however. The solution I came up with was to https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr to detect tablets and then loaded the stylesheet manually. Was going to do some further research

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question. I didn't realise you only wanted the css to be applied to tablets and not to computers with screens the same size as the tablets. Out of interest, is there any reason you want to target tablets specifically? Wouldn't the tablet styles be just as useful for small computer screens?

Comment: It was more of a performance thing, the particular page I was doing wasn't performing well on iPads, we instead used an adaptive version of the mobile page